# Array definition in XML?

Tags: xml, arrays

In XML, how do I declare array of integers?

I can declare it as the following:

```xml
<numbers type="array">
    <value>3</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>1</value>
</numbers>
```

but may be there's simpler way like this?

```xml
<numbers [3,2,1]></numbers>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The second way isn't valid XML; did you mean `<numbers>[3,2,1]</numbers>`?

If so, then the first one is preferred because all you need to get the array elements is some XML manipulation. On the second one you first need to get the value of the <numbers> element via XML manipulation, then somehow parse the `[3,2,1]` text using something else.

Or if you really want some compact format, you can consider using JSON (which "natively" supports arrays). But that depends on your application requirements.

Comment: Yes, I'd be happy to use JSON or Yaml, but I have to use XML. It looks a bit strange for me that I have to wrap each number of my array with <value> and </value> tags...It's a too complex syntax for such a simple thing as numbers array.

Comment: You can always wrap them in something smaller, such as <v>3</v><v>2</v><v>1</v>, but XML isn't known for its conciseness...

Answer (score 22):

No, there is no simpler way. You only can lose the `type=array`.

```
<numbers>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>1</value>
</numbers>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good ide to remove the type attribute. If `<numbers>` includes only one element it's not clear it is an array. When type is specified as an array it will be easier to tell your xml parser what to do with the object to prevent inconsistent parsing.

Answer (score 6):

Once I've seen such an interesting construction:

```
<Ids xmlns:id="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <id:int>1787</id:int>
</Ids>
```

Answer (score -1):

As its name is "numbers" it is clear it is a list of number... So an array of number... no need of the attribute type... Although I like the principle of specifying the type of field in a type attribute...

Comment: This answer does not answer the initial question. He asked for a simpler way, not for readability improvements.

Answer (score -3):

In XML values in text() nodes.

If we write this

```xml
<numbers>1,2,3</numbers>
```

in element "`numbers`" will be one text() node with value "1,2,3".

Native way to get many text() nodes in element is insert nodes of other types in text.

Other available types is element or comment() node.

Split with element node:

```xml
<numbers>3<_/>2<_/>1</numbers>
```

Split with comment() node:

```xml
<numbers>3<!---->2<!---->1</numbers>
```

We can select this values by this XPath

```xml
//numbers/text()
```

Select value by index

```xml
//numbers/text()[3]
```

Will return text() node with value "1"