# Character not used in .NET Type Names or Type Specs

Tags: c#, types

I have a list of Types and want to merge their FullNames into a single string for storage in an `Xml` Attribute and extract with `string.Split()`.

I was just going to use '`|`' but I saw https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx and thought it better to find something also compatible with that in case I ever need to store Type Name specifications.

What simple character can I safely use as a separator?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't store the names as child elements instead? Seems like a bad idea to squeeze it all into an XML attribute

Comment: *to find something also compatible with that* > With what exactly. Your question isn't clear. `|` can't be used in type names btw.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: It can't be used in *C# language* type names... but if the OP wants to record the names of compiler-generated types as well, that could affect things. I don't know what's valid in the CLR, but we already know the C# compiler uses `<` and `>` in type names in a way which isn't valid in C# but is valid for the CLR.

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, but the argument OP brings is a piece of documentation with no reference to the use of `|` in type names. Maybe OP can't read the syntax given there, but that was what I was trying to find out.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes, I agree that the supporting evidence that the OP is citing really isn't supporting evidence at all... I'm just saying that the statement "`|` can't be used in type names" may not be accurate, depending on what you mean by "used".

Comment: Store it as an [array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098922/array-definition-in-xml) because it is one. This deals with basically all your problems. Yes, arrays are a pain in xml, but if it bothers you that much switch everything to JSON. ["\"foo["b,ar]", "fiz"] Totally works, didn't need to thing about special chars at all.

Comment: Tricky, the CLR is *very* forgiving and compilers and obfuscators do generate wonky names.  I vote for a simple whitespace character, like a space, "\t" or "\r\n".  Watch out for obfuscators.

Comment: @Ron, @Nathan - this is an exercise to minimize space used so no to child elements/arrays, JSON etc.
@Patrick - the url says that Type*Specs* can be defined using chars that TypeNames don't - e.g. '|', '&' - I don't mind what char to use but if there is a suitable one that isn't used in either spec, may as well use it.
I mentioned FullName but I want to avoid chars produced by AssemblyQualifiedName too I guess - e.g. '`', '=' and whitespace etc.